# do jQuery .first() and .last() work differently?

Tags: jquery, navigation, slideshow, addclass, removeclass

So, i'm building a simple slideshow control with this markup:

```
<div class="previous"> </div>
<div class="next"> </div>
<div class="gallery"> </div>
    <div class="image-0"> </div>
    <div class="image-1"> </div>
    <div class="image-2"> </div>
    <div class="image-3 active"> </div>
    <div class="image-8"> </div>
    <div class="image-9"> </div>
    <div class="image-10"> </div>
    <div class="image-11"> </div>
</div>
```

and i'm trying to navigate using jQuery like this:

```
$('.next').click(function() {

    $('.active').next().addClass('active');
    $('.active').first().removeClass('active');


  });
$('.previous').click(function() {

    $('.active').prev().addClass('active');
    $('.active').last().removeClass('active');

});
```

So, the first jQuery block works as expected, first assigning the `active`class to the next div and then removing it from the first. The second block should just do it the other way around, but is doesn't remove the class from the last item after adding it to the previous one.

Am i approaching this problem from the wrong side? Or do the first() and last() functions just work differently? From what i could tell from the jquery docs, this should be working.

Comment: Your code is working for me as expected http://jsfiddle.net/GYbRv/

Comment: While the code has boundary bug, the code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/6vWx6/

Comment: Thanks, liho1eye and amit_g. But what is a boundary bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle with your code, and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/K5vN4/

(use Firebug or similar to inspect the "Result" area of the fiddle.)

Comment: It does work on jsfiddle (just found out about it, really cool!), so my problem is elsewhere. Thanks!